# Facebook Graph API get all likes from a post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am very new to facebook graph api, actually I just started today so I might use some help.

My code is working perfectly, I've written a simple algorithm to list people who like a certain post, but the problem is this. Here is the JSON reply I get from graph api:

```
<br/>
{<br/>
            "likes": {<br/>
            "data": [<br/>
               {<br/>
                   "name": "NAME",<br/>
                   "id": "ID"<br/>
               },<br/>
               {<br/>
                   "name": "NAME",<br/>
                   "id": "ID"<br/>
               },<br/>
               {<br/>
                   "name": "NAME",<br/>
                   "id": "ID"<br/>
               },<br/>
               {<br/>
                   "name": "NAME",<br/>
                   "id": "ID"<br/>
               }<br/>
           ],<br/>
  "count": 22<br/>
},<br/>
"id": "POST ID",<br/>
"created_time": "DATE CREATED"<br/>
}<br/>
```

so even though there are COUNT:22 Likes, the server returns only 4 names. Is it possible to get all the names? if so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run another query on the ID of the like object asking for details (i.e. /Likes?limit=99)

Comment: is their a way i can get all likes of the post with the user id in it.or facebook return only 100 likes in one request against the post id kindly hepl me on this issue please

Answer (score 7):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/[post_id]?fields=shares,likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)
```

Facebook (v2.4+ API) counts for the post (shares + likes + comments)

**added**: please note, that 'albums' + 'photos' objects doesn't have shares, response from API will show you error message, that there is no such a property available on this object type.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/'.$post_id.'/comments?limit=0 // for comments
https://graph.facebook.com/'.$post_id.'/likes?limit=0 // for likes
```

Using facebook graph API .
Hope it helps.

===========
Update: Thanks to laviksu

> FQL and Graph API limit=0 change Currently, we have a bug where
>   limit=0 returns all results. After the migration period, specifying a
>   limit of 0 in FQL or the Graph API will return zero results.

Comment: limit=0 is a bug which after getting fixed will resolve in 0 posts. Reference : https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/06/26/october-2013-platform-changes/

Answer (score 1):

Use FQL like this:

`SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id=10151751324059927 LIMIT 1000`

Now count the number of use Id-s. But it will give you like counts only till 1000 likes

Comment: "As of August 8, 2016, FQL will no longer be available and cannot be queried." - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/